# How to animate foreground font

Tags: wpf

I want , when mouse enter button , foreground of button's font change to another color

i have this style for my button but Doesn't work Animation

```
<Style x:Key="StartButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding solid1}"> 
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Name="Body">
                    <Grid Name="Figure">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="solid1" x:Name="solid2" Color="Black"/>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        .
                        .
                        .
                     </Grid>
                  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="solid2"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color">
                                    <ColorAnimation From="Black" To="Red"
                                     Duration="0:0:1">
                                    </ColorAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                 </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
             </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Storyboard.TargetName="solid2"
```

try

```
Storyboard.Target="{StaticResource solid1}"
```

Comment: I should sue you, because of the nick name you use!